# How to apply two or more color matrix on image view

Tags: android, bitmap, mask, android-image

need help
I have code to set brightness image like this

```
float fb = (fbri *1.5f);
        ColorMatrix cmB = new ColorMatrix();
        cmB.set(new float[] { 
            1, 0, 0, 0, fb,
            0, 1, 0, 0, fb,
            0, 0, 1, 0, fb,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0   });

        ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
        colorMatrix.set(cmB);
```

and that result I save to bitmap like this

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(b2);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
        paint.setColorFilter(f);   
        c.drawBitmap(bbri, 0,0, paint);
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b2));
```

I also have code to set contrass image like this

```
  float[] cntr = new float[] { 
                scale, 0    , 0   , 0, translate,
                0    , scale, 0   , 0, translate,
                0    , 0    ,scale, 0, translate, 
                0    , 0    , 0   , 1, 0          };
                matrix.set(cntr);
```

And also I save to bitmap too , It works , but if i run brightness and contrast simultaneously , it will show white image because that bitmap it just one , and that bitmap replace with editing bitmap before , How for solution in order I can edit image with brightness and contrast simultaneously  , thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure why nobody answered you till now. 
in order for you to do that its whether you create another class which extends Bitmap or 
create different Bitmap from the original and before you click the other method just give it 
bmp =null;